# Реализация ожидания в vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Каким образом возможно реализовать в чат-боте на пайтоне фоновый(имею в виду, что в это время у пользователя была возможность выполнять и другие действия) счётчик времени обратного отсчёта? Допустим 5 минут от отправки определённого сообщения

Заранее огромное спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Используйте библиотеку [Тhreading](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-thread-modulja-threading/)**

Вы можете делать это таким образом:

```
from threading import Thread

def timing(args): # Создаем функцию
    time.sleep(args)
    # Ваш код здесь

Thread(target=timing, args=300).start() 
# Запускаем отдельный поток, который не мешает нам
```